# onreadystatechange ¿es propiedad o metodo?

Tags: javascript, object, backend

Una pregunta, al igual que `button` es un objeto y `onclick` su método a llevar a cabo cuando hago **click**, ¿Por qué `onreadystatechange` es una propiedad y no un método? ya que a `xmlhttp` (objeto) le doy `onreadystatechange` como propiedad, pero al igualarla a la función ya no es propiedad, ¿es método?. ¿Porque dice en **Internet** que es una propiedad?

```js
  boton.onclick = function(){

    //1. new objeto ajax =>
    let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // console.log(xmlhttp); // mi objeto

    //2. METHOD => A mi objeto le doy un property onreadystatechange(0-4)
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      // console.log(xmlhttp);
      console.log(xmlhttp.onreadystatechange);
      // Retorna el codigo puro (responseText = La respuesta al pedido como texto, o null si el pedido no fue exitoso o todavía no se envió.)
      let codigoPuro = xmlhttp.responseText;
      document.getElementById("resultado1").innerHTML = codigoPuro;

      //recibe codigo parseado, retorna [object Object] =>
      let codigoParseado = JSON.parse(codigoPuro);
      document.getElementById("resultado2").innerHTML = codigoParseado;


      let detalles = "Nombre de la pandilla: <b>" + codigoParseado.nombrePandilla + "</b><br>";
      detalles += "Son " + codigoParseado.miembros.length + " superhéroes de " + codigoParseado.cuidad + "<br>";
      detalles += "La más fuerte es " + codigoParseado.miembros[1].nombre + ", con " + codigoParseado.miembros[1].superpoderes.length +  " superpoderes:<br>";
      for (let i in codigoParseado.miembros[1].superpoderes) {
        detalles += " - " + codigoParseado.miembros[1].superpoderes[i] + "<br>";
      }

      document.getElementById("resultado3").innerHTML = detalles;
    }

    // abrir una llamada una solicitud(request) / (url donde quiero hacer la solicitud) / true es asincrono =>
    xmlhttp.open("GET", "archivos/superheroes.json", true);
    xmlhttp.send();




  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>JSON</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">


</head>
<body>
  <button id="boton">¡Procesar JSON!</button>
  <h4>JSON puro:</h4>
  <p id="resultado1"></p>

  <h4>JSON parseado:</h4>
  <p id="resultado2"></p>

  <h4>Objeto literal resultante:</h4>
  <p id="resultado3"></p>
  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Segun [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/onreadystatechange):

> **La propiedad** `XMLHttpRequest.onreadystatechange` contiene el
>   controlador de eventos que se invocará cuando se active el evento
>   `readystatechange`, es decir, cada vez que cambie la propiedad
>   `readyState` de `XMLHttpRequest`.

Asi que sí, es una propiedad que contiene la referencia de un callback(evento) para ser ejecutado luego.

Por ejemplo :

```js
var carro = {
   correrEvent : null,
   correr:function(){
    if(this.correrEvent!= null){
      this.correrEvent();
    }
   }
}

carro.correrEvent = function(){ alert("el carro esta corriendo") }
carro.correr();
```

En el ejemplo se ve como se utiliza la propiedad `correrEvent` donde el usuario se subscribe y al cuando corre, si esta asignado, se ejecuta.

Es parecido a los `event` de C# que pueden ser referenciados como propiedades pero ejecutados como métodos:

```
public class Ejemplo{
  public event EventHandler MyEvent;

  public void EjecutarEvento()
  {
       MyEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty); // se ejecuta como metodo
  }
}

new Ejemplo().MyEvent += (a,b)=>{ } // asignos el evento
```

Answer (score 0):

En Javascript [una función es un objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function):

```js
var suma= new Function('param1','param2','return param1 + param2');
console.log(suma(3,5));
```

Por tanto distinguir entre propiedad/atributo y método no tiene mucho sentido. Además, puede ser que una propiedad admita más de un tipo.

Answer (score 0):

Se habla de métodos cuando son funciones que ya vienen en el prototipo del objeto, por lo tanto, cuando obtienes una instancia del tal objeto, esa función viene ya definida.

Cuando obtienes la referencia el objeto (HTMLElement) del botón, se trata de una instancia de `HTMLElement` que ya tiene la función `click` luego es un **método de la instancia** del botón.

```js
var boton=document.getElementById('boton');
console.log(boton.click); // ya es una función
```

```html
<button id="boton">hola</button>
```

En el otro caso, cuando instancias `XMLHttpRequest` ésta no tiene una **función** `onreadystatechange`. Es simplemente una `propiedad` cuyo valor inicial tipo `null`. Hasta que tú la sobreescribes, no se convierte en una función.

```js
let xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
console.log(xmlhttp.onreadystatechange) // es una propiedad con valor null
```

Sin embargo, al redeclarar `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` como función sí la estás convirtiendo en un método de la instancia.